# Issue related in creating the log file in server location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I am developing the spring boot application and use the default logback as the  logging framework.

I have my logback-spring.xml in /resources/dev

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="/home/myadmin/APACHE/AppServer/Tomcat/logs" />
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}/test.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I have created the profile in pom.xml as below

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
                <tomcat.deploy.url>http://12.15.47.147:8080/manager/text</tomcat.deploy.url>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I build the project from build server I am getting the FileNotFoundException saying /home/myadmin/APACHE/AppServer/Tomcat/logs/test.log is not found. It seems the profiling doesn't work here.

Can any one please suggest what does cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions :

1.Ensure that you have the permission needed for the file like (read,write etc.)

2.Check the location of the file using below command whether it exists or not.

```
grep -r test.log webapps
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have changed the logback configuration file as logback-spring-dev.xml and the error is no more exists but the log file is not generating inside the tomcat log folder. Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Provide permission for the log folder in which writing the log file.